# MPC-HC Seekbar Not Jumping to Correct Position with Mouse Click

Tags: mouse, media-player-classic

On my MPC-HC video player installation, the seekbar is not moving to the correct position whenever I click to move it. Instead, it moves either slightly ahead or behind where my cursor clicks. Since I can't really come up with a good way to describe the problem, I have made a gif animation of me demonstrating the problem. The red flashes represent when I click. Normally, the seekbar should jump to where the red flashes, but it doesn't as you can see. What could be the problem? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it multiples times, and each time I have made sure that no source files were left over.

[image: Seekbar Issue]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A user on the MPC-HC IRC channel under the username "JEEB" informed me that I likely have a feature in MPC-HC known as "Fast Seek" enabled. Sure enough, this was the problem. I turned it off under `View->Options->Tweaks->Fast seek (on keyframe)`, and it solved the problem.